Minimum dominating subgraph
A graph G(V,E) is defined by a set of vertices V and a set of edges E. Given W⊆V, find a connected subgraph G'(V',E') of G that satisfies the following conditions:
i) ∀p∈V,∃p'∈V' such that p′ is adjacent to p; or p∈V′;
ii) ⊆′;
iii) Under the conditions of i) and ii), the size of ′ is minimized.

Why is this being defined in terms of a subgraph? E' isn't used for anything. This seems to just be a weird statement of the dominating set problem.

You can think of this as a variation of the dominating set problem. In the minimum dominating set problem, the vertex set does not require connectivity. However, in this problem, since a graph is required, the final vertex set must be connected. You are correct that E' does not actually play a functional role here; I only used E' to express the existence of G ′ .

"However, in this problem, since a graph is required, the final vertex set must be connected." - graphs don't have to be connected. If you want a connected subgraph, you should say so.

In that case, what you're dealing with is the connected dominating set problem.

You are right, I have corrected the description of this question, thank you.
